# Gallery Image in Android is Flipped but with Camera is Correct

Tags: android, camera, image-gallery, image-rotation

```
switch (requestCode)
{
    case GALLERY_REQUEST:
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        profilePhoto = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        ivUserProfile.setImageBitmap(profilePhoto);
        //ivUserProfile.setRotation(-90);
        break;

    case  CAMERA_REQUEST:
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        profilePhoto = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ivUserProfile.setImageBitmap(profilePhoto);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, in detail, what "flipped" means.

Comment: Rotated -90 degree when captured with gallery using this code.